# Open a PDF at a logical page number

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've searched high and low for a way to open a PDF at a 'Logical Page Number' but so far haven't found any solution.

What I mean by 'Logical Page Number' is the following (highlighted):

[image: Logical Page Number]

I've tried using the following calls directly over an URL, but none of them work:

```
example.org/doc.pdf#nameddest=R5
example.org/doc.pdf#page=R5
example.org/doc.pdf#bookmark=R5
example.org/doc.pdf#R5
```

It seems that in iTextSharp you can only open a page at an integer value.

Does anyone have any idea how a logical page number can be used to open a PDF at its relative page number with iTextSharp?

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29164945/1729265) Bruno Lowagie explains how to retrieve an array of all the page labels in a file. You can find the integer index of your desired page by finding the position of that label in that array and adding 1 as page numbers are 1-based.